# Store images temporary in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, hosting

I'm writing an app with Python, which will check for updates on a website(let's call it A) every 2 hours, if there are new posts, it will download the images in the post and post them to another website(call it B), then delete those images.
Site B provide API for upload images with description, which is like:
`upload(image_path, description)`, where `image_path` is the path of the image on your computer.
Now I've finished the app, and I'm trying to make it run on Google App Engine(because my computer won't run 7x24), but it seems that GAE won't let you write files on its file system.
How can I solve this problem? Or are there other choices  for free Python hosting and providing "cron job" feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GAE has a BlobStore API, which can work pretty much as a file storage, but probably it's not what you whant. Actually, the right answer depends on what kind of API you're using - it may support file-like objects, so you could pass urllib response object, or accept URLs, or tons of other interesting features

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to use temporary storage at all - just download the image with urlfetch into memory, then use another urlfetch to upload it to the destination site.